# How to move a pie chart down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I have created a `pie chart` with the following code.

```
customeractivity
.width(262)
.height(120)
.slicesCap(5)
.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#FFDA33","#05BCDC","#EA7262","#0071CF","#58A531","#E51F30"]))
.dimension(Age_GrpDimension)
.group(Age_GrpGroup)
.legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(16).itemHeight(15).gap(3)) 

.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
        return  Math.round(dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100)*10)/10+ '%';
    })
});

customeractivity.render();
```

The `pie chart` looked like this:

[image]

Do anyone know how to move this pie chart down?
I tried adding `space`, but it had some side effects. So, I'm stuck now. Please help me out.

Comment: Explain clearly down means you want to roll that

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @SamudralaRamu: I just want to move the pie chart down by leaving space between the heading **Forecast Customer Activity**

Comment: @AndyHolmes: jquery.min.js,bootstrap.min.js,d3.js,dc.js,https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js

Comment: a wild guess: .legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(16).itemHeight(15).gap( **10** ))

Comment: @HaraldErnst that wont work.

Comment: Can you try to add a  .padding(10) to customeractivity object?

Comment: This wont work either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  tag for the heading **Forecast Customer Activity**,then use `padding` to move the chart down. Try the following code.

```
<div class="x_content" style="margin: 20px 0px 0px -24px;color:black;width:200px;height:255px;background:#ffffff;border:1px solid black;">
<h style="margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:13px;"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Forecast Customer Activity</b></h>
<div id="customeractivity" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;">
</div>
</div>
```